# dataproc hive count mismatch for partition tables

Tags: hadoop, hive, google-cloud-platform, hadoop2, google-cloud-dataproc

I have tables on dataproc hadoop cluster which already contains data and they are stable.

but when i put additional partitions to it and repair, it still give me row count of older state.

so new partitions are added to metastore but still new row count is not reflected.

but when i recreate the table and then repair, the new row count is reflected.

so row count query that i had executed are not using metastore stats, MR job is exexuted for row count.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have steps to reproduce? (e.g., example hive DDL, query, data layout, etc)

Comment: @AngusDavis, earlier it was working fine but now for every partition table same issue is reproducable. So table scheme is not the issue.
supprising fact is that if table is recreate then row count is good.

Comment: Can you include an example DDL to help in debugging? There are of course many options that can be specified when creating tables, knowing which set you're using will help diagnose what's going on. The Dataproc image version would also be useful.

Comment: @AngusDavis 
example ddl 
CREATE TABLE mytable (
wban INT, 
date STRING
) 
PARTITIONED BY (bid STRING)
STORED AS ORC
 LOCATION ‘ gs://mybucket/hive/mytable’;
 dataproc version 1.2.

supprising today for all tables when i tried to reproduce this scenario actually rowcount was matching with the data.

Comment: As an experiment, when you've found a reproducible case of this, try running: ANALYZE TABLE mytable PARTITION(bid) COMPUTE STATISTICS and see if that changes the behavior. I know that in your original comment it's indicated an MR is run to compute this, but I do wonder if the metadata is being used in some way and not being updated with MSCK REPAIR.

Comment: @AngusDavis 
so when i tried metastore was updated with new partitions and i have already tried analyzing stats and even setting compute query using metastore stat to false for rowcount. even file permission looks good.
is there any other option that i left please suggest.